# Is Map<String, Collection<Object>> possible to declare in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

I have a class with the following constructor:

```
public MyClass(Map<String s, Collection<Object>> co){
    //impl
}
```

I need to invoke it via Spring bean's declarations. I tried to do something like this:

```
<bean id="toInject" class="path.toSomClass" />

<bean id="myBean" class="path.to.MyClass">
    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
            <entry key="String" 
        value-ref="_WHAT_SHOULD_I_WRITE_HERE_TO_DECLARE_A_COLLECTION_FROM_THE_ONLY_toInject">
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

I'm not concerned about the type of the `Collection` (It may be a `List<T>` as well as `Set<T>`, or anything else implementing `Collection<T>`).

Comment: What is element type in Collection?

Comment: @Loc They are just `Object`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a [`<list>`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-collection-elements) element as part of the value for the entry, like this:

```xml
<bean id="myBean" class="path.to.MyClass">
    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
            <entry key="String">
                <list>
                    <ref bean="toInject" />
                </list>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

Dependency injection happens at runtime, so no type arguments exist anymore at that time.

This configuration should work:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="path.to.MyClass">
    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
            <entry key="String">
                <list>
                     <value>Your value here, or</value>
                     <ref bean="yourBeanHere" />
                </list>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```